# Deploying ClickOne application with network share

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

We have a server PC and other client PCs working connected to server using LAN. We have a application for our internal use which is developed using VB.Net. I used steps in  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17003/ClickOnce-Quick-steps-to-Deploy-Install-and-Update to deploy clickone statergy for updating our application.After publishing while installing application,this error is coming

[image]

I searched i details and found this error

```
ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of D:\Desktop\publish\Global.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading file:///D:/Desktop/publish/Application Files/Global_1_0_0_0/Global.XmlSerializers.dll.deploy did not succeed.
    + Could not find file 'D:\Desktop\publish\Application Files\Global_1_0_0_0\Global.XmlSerializers.dll.deploy'.
    + Could not find file 'D:\Desktop\publish\Application Files\Global_1_0_0_0\Global.XmlSerializers.dll.deploy'.
    + Could not find file 'D:\Desktop\publish\Application Files\Global_1_0_0_0\Global.XmlSerializers.dll.deploy'.
```

I have checked Application files in publish options and Global.XmlSerializers.dll is included. Anyone know why this is happening?

Is there any way to copy some extra files to installation folder(C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Apps..) when installing or updating clickone application? Because we use some outside support files for our application. Is it possible?

Is there any way to pass argument to clickone application short cut,like passing argument to .exe shortcut("\Global.exe" ?/?customer?/?)?

**EDIT:**
This is how I published

[image]

I checked by giving network path for publishing folder location.But same error coming.

Here is application files included

As you can see Global.XmlSerializers.dll is included

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there no magic involved in ClickOnce: you can just look into the deployment folder - is the required file there or not?

If not, you need to change the settings in the Publish options for the required file. This message - in my experience - is *always* a sign that one of the required assemblies has not been published.

---

In addition it seems that you published to a mapped network drive instead of publishing to an UNC path. You need to publish to a path following the `\\server\name\` scheme.

Comment: I have already looked into the deployment folder and Global.XmlSerializers.dll file was not there.As I already mentioned Global.XmlSerializers.dll was included in publishing application files.But I don't know why that file is not published. That  s what I want to know

Comment: Can you create a screenshot of the Publish Options page?

Comment: Oh, could it also be that you did not actually publish to a network location? This may also be the mistake, as the installation is looking for the files in D:\!! You need to publish to folders following the  `\\server\name` scheme.

Comment: I have edited my question.please check. The actual problem is my publish folder doesn't contain Global.XmlSerializers.dll.

Comment: You see? `Global.XmlSerializers.dll` is set to `Include (Auto)`. Change that to `Include` and it will get published. Some DLLs are not published if set to `Include (Auto)`, because there's a separate installer. This, for example, is also true for the local reporting components.

Comment: What's not working? Isn't it getting published or can't you run your application? If not getting published: Are you looking in the right folder? If you can't run: Did you publish to an UNC path now instead of a mapped network drive?

Comment: 'Global.XmlSerializers.dll' is not getting published.I tried to publish to an UNC path also.Result is same.

Comment: Actually that can't be. If you set the publish option to `Include` the file will be published always. Did you set the "Local copy" flag to "true" in the properties of the reference to that library? This may also influence the behavior, but usually it's enough to change the publish option.

Comment: I hadn't added reference to Global.XmlSerializers.dll. Only reference added files will be published? I have added reference to Global.XmlSerializers.dll and checked,it worked fine for one time.If i publish again with different version Global.XmlSerializers.dll not published.Its working fine if I remove and add reference to Global.XmlSerializers.dll every time I do publish.Why is that? And "Local copy" flag is set to "true".Any way to publish files whose reference is not added?

Comment: The file doesn't need to be referenced actually. For example, when you use the Reporting components, two references will be added to your project, but another DLL will be included in the list of published files. Unless you configure it to `Include` instead of the default `Include (Auto)`, it won't be published and the application won't work. Setting the publish option should be enough.

Comment: Is there any way to pass argument to clickone application shortcut?

Comment: The purpose of which being...?

Comment: Actually we were installing application in server and put .exe shortcut on all users PCs.We use same application with different databases by passing database name as argument to .exe shortcut. So i want to do same thing with clickone application.

Comment: Well, there's a `Main` method in `Program.cs` that can take arguments - so why don't you just try?

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for a file on the D: drive.  It is unlikely that your users all have their D drive mapped to the same location. When you publish you should use the full path rather than mapped drive letters.

//Servername/shareddirectory/appdirectory

Does the install work for you?

Comment: Use UDP addresses instead of addresses relative to virtual / mapped network drives when deploying click-once

Comment: I have checked that.It is not working.And I don't think that is the problem because I checked publish folder and it doesn't contain Global.XmlSerializers.dll file

Answer (score 0):

When I have used the wizard and deployed to a network share, in the Publish Wizard:

`Specify the location to publish this application:`

**UDP Path**

Click Next

`How will users install the application?`

`From a UNC path of file share`

`Specify the UNC path:`

**The same UDP Path (copy pasted from before)**